How to show AlertDialog from AsyncValue `error` callback?
I am using Riverpod to load my data from an API, and I'm working on error handling.   If the API request fails, I want to show an AlertDialog.
In the code below, I'm watching vehiclesList, and handling the resulting AsyncValue when callbacks.  For error I want to show an AlertDialog with an action that returns to the previous screen:
class VehiclesListScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const VehiclesListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

   final vehiclesList = ref.watch(vehiclesProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CommonAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          vehiclesList.when(
            data: (vehicles) {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: vehicles.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        InkWell(
                          onTap:() {
                            final selectedVehicle = vehicles[index];
                            final vehicleId = selectedVehicle.id;
                            final location = '/vehicles_list/$vehicleId';                           
                            context.go(location);
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8),
                            title: Text(vehicles[index].make,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                              child: Text(vehicles[index].model),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                ),
              );
            },
            error: ((error, stackTrace) {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (dialogContext) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('alert!'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                            child: const Text('ok'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            })
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
                return Container(); // Because a Widget must be returned
              }),
            loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}


However, when this runs, I get an exception:

I understand this is because the Alert Dialog is being marked dirty while it's parent is already building.
I've tried getting this to work using the SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() and context.mounted approaches, but still no success.
I thought showing an AlertDialog from the error callback would be straightforward, but I cannot figure out how to get this working.
Any suggestions?  Is this even possible?
Thanks.
Updated code (snippets) after suggestions:
            error: ((error, stackTrace) {
                SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  _showAlertDialog(context);
                });
                return Container(); // Because a Widget must be returned
              }),

  _showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (dialogContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('alert!'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                child: const Text('ok'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                })
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }



You try adding a postFrameCallBack on widgetBinding. I am assuming error is called only once WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {       showDialog(...);     })

Implementation of showDialog keep outside of build and wrap showdialog method with  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {showdialogmethod();}

@Md.YeasinSheikh - yes error is called only once.   I took your suggestion, and that of @DroidFlutter, and seems to be working.    Not sure why my attempt at WidgetsBinding didn't work before.    I ended up having to call pop() twice: once for the AlertDialog, and another to return to the previous screen.  I assume this is okay?    Posting my updated code in an Edit.    Thanks for the help!

Don't use ref.watch -- ref.listen is meant for this.

ref.watch is meant to resolve an AsyncValue to one of its states and the callback is meant to be called declaratively (like returning a widget on the build method). For calling actions that should be done imperatively (like showing a dialog), you should use ref.listen instead.
class VehiclesListScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const VehiclesListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen(vehiclesProvider, (prev, next) {
      // You can check for error with the .hasError property
      if (next.hasError) {
        showDialog(...);
      }

      // Alternatively, you can check if it's of type AsyncError
      if (next is AsyncError) {
        showDialog(...);
      }
    });

   final vehiclesList = ref.watch(vehiclesProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      // ...
    );
  }
}

Note that it's perfectly fine to have both ref.listen and ref.watch in the same build method.
